# Openproject 7 : File to import not found or unreadable: helpers/functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation, openproject

After a fresh install of Openproject (stable/7), I get the following error message when accessing localhost:3000 for the first time :

```
Showing /home/stephane/www/openproject8/app/views/homescreen/blocks/_upsale.html.erb where line #6 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: bundles/openproject-core-app.
```

Tutorial followed for installation :

https://www.openproject.org/development/setting-up-development-environment/

Configuration :

- ruby 2.4.1
- node 6.11.0
- rails 5.0.3
- bundler 1.15.1
- openproject stable/7 (https://github.com/opf/openproject/tree/stable/7 )

I suspect an issue in app/assets/stylesheets/openproject.sass:43 , as indicated by the error trace... but this app should work out of the box...

Is this related to Foundation ?

Answer (score 3):

Running this command (in a separate window) solved the issue

```
RAILS_ENV=development npm run webpack-watch
```